# Angular custom style directive value is undefined at the beginning

Tags: angular

I have this custom directive that I use to set color to an icon.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[styledIcon]'
})
export class StyledIconDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @Input('styledIcon') color: string;

  @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    this.setHoverStyle();
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    this.setStyle();
  }

  setHoverStyle() {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.color = 'green';
  }

  setStyle(){
    this.el.nativeElement.style.color = this.color;
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.setStyle();
  }

}
```

And this works fine when I set the value in the html. The thing is I load the color for this style through a service. And there may be several other services which will be called before that. So I have used a `setTimeOut` below to demonstrate that scenario.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 
  customStyle: Style;

  constructor(private elementService: ElementServiceService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout (() => {
      this.customStyle= this.elementService.getColor();
    }, 5000);
    
  }
}
```

Below is the html which uses the style. The style sets and the icon color is changed after 5 seconds. But until then the customStyle is undefined. And I get and error in the console **(ERROR TypeError: ctx_r1.customStyle is undefined**). Is there a way to avoid the console error.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of (menuItems$|async)" class="col-lg-3">
     <fa-icon [icon]="item.icon" [styledIcon]="customStyle.color" size="2x"></fa-icon>
</div>
```

`customStyle?.color` doesn't work cause it doesn't set the style after 5 seconds

Comment: Can you please reproduce this issue in stackblitz?

Comment: are You using `customStyle?color` or `customStyle?.color` because it does do difference

Comment: I'm using ```customStyle?.color```

Comment: Do you use OnPush change detection?

Comment: No, I'm not using OnPush change detection

Comment: It works as expected https://ng-run.com/edit/fjuD6LashWhqIkFyc3f4

Comment: Colour doesn't change to red after 5 seconds. It changes once you hovered over the text because of the hover effect added in the StyleIcon directive. Otherwise it would remain as black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show icons only if `customStyle` is not undefined

```
<div *ngFor="let item of (menuItems$|async)" class="col-lg-3">
    <fa-icon *ngIf="customStyle" [icon]="item.icon" [styledIcon]="customStyle.color" size="2x"></fa-icon>
</div>
```

or

```
<div *ngIf="customStyle"> 
    <div *ngFor="let item of (menuItems$|async)" class="col-lg-3">
        <fa-icon [icon]="item.icon" [styledIcon]="customStyle.color" size="2x"></fa-icon>
    </div>
</div>
```

this way HTML will render only when `customStyle` is not undefined

Answer (score 0):

The value customStyle.color is not available as customStyle itself is `undefined` at time of init. customStyle is populated later when setTImeout resolves.

Could you try like this

```
<fa-icon [icon]="item.icon" [styledIcon]="customStyle?.color" size="2x"></fa-icon>
```

Comment: customStyle?.color doesn't set the style after 5 seconds. Icons are displayed in black

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default Initialization to your property "customStyle"

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  customStyle: Style = {
    ///
    color: 'ffffff'
  }
...
}
```

In this case, your ngOnit will replace the default value once setTimeOut finishes.

I would suggest you to return a Promise or Observable from "this.elementService.getColor()" and await for the response and fill your customStyleProperty. Because, what if your service takes more than 5 seconds.

Comment: Setting initial color doesn't work either. It's like using customStyle?.color. Initial values doesn't get replaced after 5 seconds.

Comment: directive.ts
 `@Input('styledIcon') color: string;`

Please add single quote for `" 'customStyle.color' "`  because it's a string


`<div *ngFor="let item of (menuItems$|async)" class="col-lg-3">
     <fa-icon [icon]="item.icon" [styledIcon]="'customStyle.color'" size="2x"></fa-icon>
</div>`